# PHP: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() while dynamic data Export?

Tags: php, foreach

Getting error while Printing dynamic data in phpexcel - Error Invalid Argument while printing data from my MYSQL Database

```
$labels = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query_result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $labels[$i++] = $row1["label"];
} 
  foreach($labels[0] as $ind=>$label){ //error invalid argument
        $letter = range('A', 'Z')[$ind];
        $tmp = explode('>',$label); 
        $col_names[] = $tmp[0];
        echo $letter.'1'."\r\n";

        echo "Column -> $tmp[0] \r\n"; 
}  

    foreach ($labels as $ind=>$item){ //Error invalid Argument

    $index = $ind + 2;

foreach($item as $ind2=>$data){

      $letter = range('A', 'Z')[$ind2];

    $val = explode('>',$data);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("$letter$index",$val[1]);

}

}
```

My **Var_dump($labels) output is**

```
  array(15) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "EY"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "PWC"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Deloitte"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "KPMG"
  [4]=>
  string(14) "Grant Thornton"
  [5]=>
```

I Added my Whole Code Please Once Please

it is giving **invalid argument error**

Comment: $labels[0] is not an array.

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: you could do `foreach($labels...` thats an array but `$labels[0]` is a scalar value

Comment: ` foreach ($labels as $ind=>$item){
        
        $index = $ind + 2;
        
    foreach($item as $ind2=>$data){
         
      $letter = range('A', 'Z')[$ind2];
        
      echo "$letter$index \r\n";
        
        $val = explode('>',$data);
       
    }
    echo "\r\n\r\n";
    } 
` also this code have same error? why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `$labels[0]` is not an array, `$labels` however is.

**Change:**

```
foreach($labels[0] as $ind=>$label){
```

**To:**

```
foreach($labels as $ind => $label) {
```

[Further reading.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

---

**Expanding based on your comments:**

```
foreach($labels as $ind => $label) {

    $index = $ind + 2;

    $letter = range('A', 'Z')[$ind2];
    $val = explode('>', $data);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($letter . $index, $val[1]);

}
```

Comment: ` foreach ($labels as $ind=>$item){
        
        $index = $ind + 2;
        
    foreach($item as $ind2=>$data){
         
      $letter = range('A', 'Z')[$ind2];
        
      echo "$letter$index \r\n";
        
        $val = explode('>',$data);
       
    }
    echo "\r\n\r\n";
    } 
` it happens with this code too

Comment: That's because `$item` is not an array, you are trying to iterate through a string.

Comment: well i appreciate if you could help me to do it in better way!

Comment: If you do a `var_dump($labels);` just before you do `foreach($labels` and post the result in your question, I should be able to fix this for you.

Comment: I changed please check @MarkOverton

Comment: I've updated my answer but I need more information, what're you trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to print row and column dynamically in phpexcel through array but i am trying to print array[0] always see this is my old question which is unsolved [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60164051/phpexcel-dynamic-row-and-column-incrementing-is-not-working-for-array-in-phpexc)

Comment: Please see revised answer